# Nested Pundit policies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

Say I have a Document model that belongs to a User model.  A User has_many documents.  DocumentPolicy might include this...

```
def edit?
  document.user_id == user.id
end
```

But, what if...to edit a document you must also be able to edit that documents parent (User).  Then, the policy might look like this.

```
def edit?
  document.user_id == user.id &&
  policy(user).edit?
end
```

This results in the error:

```
undefined method `policy' for #<DocumentPolicy
```

I'm curious if there is a better way to do this.  Am I approaching it incorrectly?  It seems like something that others would have thought to do...so, Im hoping to get insight on how others have approached this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had the right idea, you just needed to call it through the pundit class explicitly:

```
def edit?
  # I am assuming that a user can edit themselves, so the "or" is in there, if not, go back to using and
  document.user_id == user.id or UserPolicy.new(user, User.find(document.user_id)).edit?
end
```

That should give you what you wanted.

Comment: calling the class directly...so simple...how'd I miss it.  Thanks!  This works great.

Answer (score 0):

In your Document Controller, declare the user variable and authorize that user.

```
def edit
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(@document.user_id)  #or how you define it
  authorize @user
end
```

Then pundit will look in your User Policy for the edit? method.

**edit  regarding the error message, it is saying that your Document model has no policy file associated to it.  If you look in your policies folder you should see user_policy.rb but not document_policy.rb  (app/controllers/policies)

Comment: That will only work if the Document controller edit action is actually hit.  However, often with Pundit you want to use policies to limit link access (i.e. edit_document_path if policy) in the view...before the action is ever hit.  Also, (I notice your new to SO...and maybe to rails??)...user = User.find(@document.user_id) should be user = @document.user.

Comment: And, that is not at all what that error message indicates.  What it says is that the method policy() is not defined when accessed from within the DocumentPolicy.  Which is the basis of my question...Pundit does not seem to allow nested policies.

Comment: I guess I am newer to rails than you.  So @document.user is better because it's not another query to the db?  Anyhow I misread your error and code, to get back to you question, can you just user authorize user instead of policy(user)?

Comment: Its better because it is shorter and cleaner.  Your still hitting the db.  Could do Document.includes(:user).find(params[:id) then document.user would not hit the db.  For, my question...I'm looking for a way to nest policies...it needs to be done at the policy level.